Completion of the universal cover of a solid cone minus an axis
On Thurston The Geometry and Topology of Three-Manifolds 4.4 there is a statement, 

The completion of I is clearly the solid cone, obtained by adjoining the z-axis to
I.
It follows easily that the completion of $\tilde{I}$
is also obtained by adjoining a single copy of the z-axis.

where I is the solid cone minus its axis (z-axis) and the fist sentence above implies that I should contain its boundary cone. $\tilde{I}$ is its universal cover. They are in the hyperbolic upper half space modle. And here the definition of completetion should be the usual metric completion in the sence of Hopf-Rinow theorem.
I think the universal covering of I should be the following map
$ (x,y,z)\mapsto (z exp(x+iy), z) $, where $x\leq0, y\in \mathbb{R}, z>0$.
But in this case the completion of $\tilde{I}$ is made by adding a half plane at $z=0$ and one point at infinity to it, the second sentence of Thurston does not make sense.
The question is: Is the covering map correct? And (by correcting the covering map, or do something else) how does the second sentence of Thurstion make sense?

No, the completion of $\tilde I$ is not made as you describe it.
Motivated by thinking about one $z=c$ horoball at a time, perhaps it would help to think of this one dimension lower.
Consider $X = \mathbb R^2 - \mathcal O$, where $\mathcal O = (0,0)$, and put the standard Euclidean metric on $X$. The completion of $X$ is then obtained by adding the one point $\mathcal O$.
Now consider the universal cover $\tilde X$. We can lift polar coordinates on $\mathbb R^2 - \mathcal O$ to get coordinates $(r,\theta) \in (0,\infty) \times (-\infty,+\infty)$ for $\tilde X$, and this gives a diffeomorphism
$$\tilde X \approx (0,\infty) \times (-\infty,+\infty)
$$
But don't be fooled by this diffeomorphism: it does not follow that the completion of $\tilde X$ is obtained by adding a whole line $\{0\} \times (-\infty,+\infty)$. We must take into account the correct form of the lifted Euclidean metric on $\tilde X$ expressed in lifted polar coordinates:
$$ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 \, d\theta^2, \qquad (r,\theta) \in (0,\infty) \times (-\infty,+\infty)
$$
In fact the completion of $\tilde X$ with respect to this metric is obtained by adding a single point: with a bit of thought you can convince yourself, using the above formula for $ds^2$, that a Cauchy sequence $(r_i,\theta_i)$ in $\tilde X$ diverges in $\tilde X$ if and only if $\lim r_i=0$, and furthermore all divergent Cauchy sequences in $\tilde X$ are equivalent to each other. The completion is therefore a single point.
Back to $\tilde I$, you can carry out the same argument on the intersection of $I$ with each horoball $z = $(constant), to show that the completion of $\tilde I$ is obtained by adding one point per horoball, i.e. by adding one point for each point on the positive $z$-axis, i.e. by adding one line.
